# chrome extensions message-passing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop (for the moment!) a simple chrome extension using the message exchanging API.

My contentscript ask the background page for its url, and wait the background answer.
However, my contentscrpt never get the answer. Why? Thanks for your answer.

**content_script.js**

```
/**
 * Retrieve the url or the page currently visited.
 */
 chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action' : 'getUrl'}, function(response) {
    alert(response.url);
 });
```

**background.html**

```
...
                
   function onRequest(request, sender, callback) {  
      sendResponse({'url' : sender.tab.url});                       
   };

   chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onRequest` function has the final parameter named `callback`, but you call `sendResponse` in it. Assuming this is what your actual code looks like, you'll need to make the two names the same. If you inspect the background page in the developer tools, you should see a JavaScript exception about `sendResponse` being undefined.